# Need to understand everything in pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, procedure

My company uses Oracle 11g. I am new to Pl/sql and I know only basic SQL. I am not aware of the below things in Oracle pl/sql:

```
1.creating procedures
2.creating jobs
3.api calling
4.batch running
5.metalized view
6.DB links
7.configuring mail alerts from Database.
8.all pl/sql concepts
```

Where can I learn all this simple and easily?
Kindly suggest some best YouTube channels, websites, best courses, eBooks or any platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [Oracle 10g documentation homepage](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/index.htm). Yes, I know, you said you're on 11g, but never mind that. Page I suggested is nicely divided into several sections - have a look at **Most Popular**.

- as you're new to Oracle, read **Concepts** first
- as you know a little bit of SQL, read **SQL Reference** next; you *must* know SQL before you move on to
- **PL/SQL User's Guide and Reference** book, which will teach you what you asked for
- don't miss **Application Developer's Guide - Fundamentals** as the last book I'm going to suggest in this answer

Feel free to find similar books related to your Oracle database version; there will be some differences, but - as *fundamentals* - previously mentioned literature will be just fine.

Answer (score -2):

I guess you can start from this one
[https://www.amazon.com/Oracle-PL-SQL-Programming-Versions/dp/1449324452/ref=sr_1_1?crid=3OTIP644USUIY&keywords=oracle+pl%2Fsql&qid=1636468646&qsid=136-1702536-3186447&sprefix=oracle+pl%2Caps%2C373&sr=8-1&sres=1449324452%2CB00TFOGOSE%2C097615739X%2C1890774804%2C0071812431%2C1491920009%2C1946383112%2C0596514107%2C0071835148%2C1133947360%2CB004PYDRMK%2C0596514468%2CB014V7G3UI%2C1785284800%2C0072261943%2CB08YQCNT4C&srpt=ABIS_BOOK](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449324452)

if link does not work then
Oracle PL/SQL Programming: Covers Versions Through Oracle Database 12c Sixth Edition
by Steven Feuerstein (Author), Bill Pribyl (Author)

Comment: does this covers all topics i mentioned above??

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I am quite sure in this book you will find  "creating procedures", "all pl/sql concepts".  "creating jobs" - for this one you need book about Oracle administration (e.g. Darl Kunh "Pro Oracle Database 18c Administration"). "api calling" - no idea, "batch running" - please describe in more details what you want to run. "materialized view"-Darl Kunh "Pro Oracle Database 18c Administration", "DB links"-? "configuring mail alerts from Database" not sure

Comment: @HappyMan The only place that covers all the topics is the documentation. Really. Oracle has very good documentation, and Concepts is a good starting point. All the other docs may be read when you face some specific task, because just reading is completely useless.